# android - onCreateView de fragment se ejecuta varias veces

Tags: android, android-fragment

Estoy usando mobile navigation y tengo 5 fragments definidos en el que son principales y varios secundarios. En el primer fragment cuando presiono un boton salto hacia otro fragment en esa misma vista y luego al virar hacia el fragment padre de este se vuelve a ejecutar el onCreateView. Como puedo evitar ese comportamiento indeseado? Este es el onCreateView.

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        bindUI(root);

        initButtonsCards();

        setupRecyclerView();

        return root;
    }
```

**Edit:**
Agrego el codigo del bindUI

```
private void bindUI(View root) {
        mRecyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        context = root.getContext();

        // Setup exit transition on first fragment
        setExitTransition(new Fade());

        fabCreateTrip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //logica del boton
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Podrías colocar el código del método `bindUI(root)`?

Comment: @DavidVillegas ya edite la pregunta